# Android Overlay View makes some applications pause

Tags: android, overlay

I have created an overlay activity the requests permission to create a window of type TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY and then starts a service that creates the window. This all works fine and I can interact with it and the launcher home screen behind the view (It's just a search text box with interactive results as you type).

The problem is, I have found one application that when I have this overlay running, the application is frozen like it's paused (it's a game). But I have tried my overlay over other applications and it works fine like google maps and even another game.

Here is how I'm creating the window in the service

```
//Add the view to the window.
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

//Specify the view position
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;        //Initially view will be added to top-left corner
params.x = 0;

//Add the view to the window
mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
mWindowManager.addView(mFloatingView, params);
```

I've also tried other apps like facebook chat heads on top of this problem application and the app works with them so it has to be doable.

Has anyone run into this before? I'm really new to Android programming so I'm just not sure what to look for

Thanks!

**EDIT**I found that if I use FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE then the problem app works underneath it. But then I can't interact with the overlay :/

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the opposite. How do I get a TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY window to pause any underlying window's activity? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

That application might have some code written in its `onPause()` method to freeze it. Usually games pause themselves in `onStop()` or in `onPause()`, so that user doesn't accidentally lose their progress. Like if a phone call comes, or they press the home or recents button.

Comment: I had wondered that myself, but didn't know how the overlay window interacted with the system and if the framework did tell the game it was paused or not. And since the facebook chatheads work, it has to be something I'm doing.

Comment: There is a simple way to check it. Create a new project, and see if its `onPause` and `onStop()` methods are being called with this overlay and with facebook chat heads.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out based on this class of the Floaties library.

https://github.com/ericbhatti/floaties/blob/master/FloatiesLibrary/floaties/src/main/java/com/bezyapps/floatieslibrary/Floaty.java

The window manager can update view params via the updateViewLayout method. Just have to remove the FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE and re-add it in the two different states of my overlay when I want to be able to input text or not